# Select diagonally table cells with mouse drag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table 4x3 and  I find it difficult to deal with the diagonal table cell selection. I used this code as a base http://jsfiddle.net/5VXDt/1/. But, when I click to a table cell and drag it diagonally, unnecessary cells are marked as well. For example if I go for B and F cells more cells will be marked. Same goes for the A, E and I. How  can I select only the diagonal only table cells?

```
 <table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>J</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>I</td>
    <td>K</td>      
  </tr>
</table>
```

The js and the css code are same

Comment: Is there a question? Your code is correct and does what it is supposed to do.. unless you want something else, then please describe it.

Comment: @Rouby i want to select only the diagonal cells when i go for diagonal selection...not other table cells

Comment: The way I read this is: I used the code at "link", I don't know what it does or how it does it so please fix it for me. kthxbye :|

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to select only the cells matching a rectangular pattern:

You need to swap out your `slice` with a more complex approach, since you dont want to color a range, but multiple sections of your array of cells.

The array for your example looks like

`[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I]`

When the user starts drag at index `2` (B) and drags to `5` (F) your code will color the range from `2` to `5`. Which would include `3` (D).

So rather than simply calculate the range, you need to calculate the column and row offsets for your start and end position.

If every row and every column has a fixed size (in your example 3) this becomes somewhat easy to calculate:

`var column = index % 3;`
and
`var row = Math.floor(index / 3);`

Then you simply iterate from the starting row to the ending row for each column (between start column and end column).

You can look at this quick example-code:

http://jsfiddle.net/5VXDt/537/

Comment: I did not understand it.

Comment: Can you be more specifc?

Comment: In order to be highlighted only the [B] and the [F], or anything that is diagonal, why should I calculate the range?

Comment: I dont mean to be rude, but do you understand what your code does and why?

Comment: No, i don't understand the code. I'm new to javascript